# JavaScript Regular Expression length issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day,

I'm trying to get the length of an value interred into a input field. The value entered needs to be 13 characters long, no less no more. And must be numerical numbers.

Here is my JS code:

```
value = '8312258066038';
re = new RegExp('^\d{13}$');
alert(re.match(value));
```

The answer is supposed to be true if the value is 13 characters.

Comment: You have an error in your code: `TypeError: re.match is not a function`. I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use test() not match()

```
value = '8312258066038';
re = /^\d{13}$/;
alert(re.test(value));
```